# Empty page on opening a ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, event-viewer

We have a website running on IIS 7 which have multiple Application pools.

The Default App Pool runs on .NET 2.0.

The single ASP.NET MVC application runs on the ASP.NET v4.0 App Pool.

Accessing the landing page of the MVC sometimes shows an empty page or a HTTP 500 Error. Opening a page from the Default App Pool website and then opening the MVC App mostly works.

I start logging the moment the landing page is opened and the user does not reach the application at all when the empty page or HTTP 500 Error is shown.

What could be causing this erratic behavior? Where should I be looking?

IIS logs, Event Viewer?

Where should I be looking?

UPDATE:

IIS Log: I see HTTP 500 responses and then HTTP 200 responses, but no way to understand why the 500 response came in the first place.

Event viewer: The Custom Views->Server Roles->Web Server has only information, which has App Pool which timed out for many other applications.

The System Event ("WAS") had one thing which might be interesting:
"A worker process with process id of '6224' serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed."

Comment: You would almost certainly see more detail in Event Viewer > Application logs. From there you'll be able to diagnose the issue more accurately.

Comment: have a look in this answer whic can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17361501/3383479

Comment: Thanks Inanikian. That was not the case here. The only event viewer entry was the one I reported and I use windows authentication.